# SharePoint 2013 Service Pack 1 appears to delete the contents of wpresources

Tags: 2013, administration, service-pack

I downloaded SP 1 Mark 2 for both [Foundation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880551) and [Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880552) on 2 different farms.

In both cases, the contents of `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\wpresources` were deleted. I have some 3rd party products that deploy files here.

I don't have anti-virus installed. The folders aren't in the recycle bin. The folders were NOT missing immediately after the service pack deployment. It happened some time over the course of 3-4 days.

Is this expected? Can anybody explain what's happening here?

I installed the binaries on my 1 web server and ran `psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait` and it went through successfully. I've done this many times. I don't think it was a matter of me installing the service pack incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wpresources is meant to hold all of the supporting resources for installed web parts.  It could be images, additional code, forms, help files, etc.

I don't think, this is SP1 issue, as you mentioned...You install it and run the config wizard via psconfig tool and no issue reported.

Did you run the Config Wizard via GUI after that?

What install in the wpresources folder, may someone uninstall the solution or something?

Also check the ULS / Event Log or more clue.

Comment: When you say "installed web parts" do you mean 3rd party web parts?  I did not run the Config wizard gui.. only psconfig from powershell.  There were images, files, pages (like you said) from the 3rd party web parts I installed.  I have 3-4 days of ULS logs to sift through.  I don't see anything related to this issue.

Comment: yes, i mean 3rd party webparts. try to run the config wizard from gui and then test it.

Comment: I'd have to try it on another server that doesn't already have the service pack applied.  May need time on that.  What difference would it make in this case if I run the psconfig via the GUI versus via powershell?

Comment: what i beleive, when you run via pwoershell, it only complete 3 steps, after that you have to run from Gui to complete the update.

Comment: I've never heard that before.  Do you have a link to some Microsoft documentation describing the differences?

Comment: the reason why i am saying....you did not run with full parameters: PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures...Ok tell me how many steps you saw to be compelted in the wizard(3 or 6)?

Comment: I don't remember how many steps completed exactly.. If I don't run the command with full parameters, could that possibly delete the contents of wpresources?

Comment: no that not true, if you did not run the config wizard completely then not of all features upated in the farm. It may be possible that complete config wizard fix the wpresources issue but...I am sure something else causing the issue(deleting the stuff from wpresources)